# The complete set of R on the subset of Z when y < 0

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, education, integers, quantifiers

Lets say we have a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ that is $$A = \{-2,-1,0,1\}$$

And we have a relation $R$ that is defined on the set $A$ such that $$xRy = \{(x,y) \in AxA: y < 0\}$$

Is this the complete set of $R$ or is it wrong?: 
$$R = \{(-2,-2),(-1,-2),(0,-2),(1,-2),(-2,-1),(-1,-1),(0,-1),(1,-2)\}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. In fact, you have to save all tge tuples $(x,y)$ such that $y<0$ and $x$ can be all number in the set $A$.
So, we have:
$$R = \{(-2,-2),(-1,-2),(0,-2),(1,-2),(-2,-1),(-1,-1),(0,-1),(1,-2)\}
$$

Comment: @Palif: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?